# If $M$ is a convex subset and $f:M\rightarrow F$ is uniformly continuous, prove that $\|f(x)-f(y)\|\leq a \|x-y\|+1$

Tags: metric-spaces

> Consider: $E,F$ normed vector spaces, $M\subset E$ a convex subset and $f:M\rightarrow F$ a uniformly continuous function. Prove that there exists $a>0$ such that: $\|f(x)-f(y)\|\leq a \|x-y\|+1$ .

I have only a suspicion of a way to prove this exercise. Since $M$ is convex, for every $a,b\in M$, the set $[a,b] = \{(1-t)a+tb:t\in[0,1]\} \subset M$. By hyphotesis $E$ is a normed vector space, so for any $x,y\in M$ we can take $x'=x/\|x\|$ and $y'=y/\|y\|$. So the set $[y',x']$ is contained in $M$. Also we can note that $\|(1-t)y'+tx'\|=\|t(x'-y')+y'\|\leq t \|x'-y'\|+\|y'\| = t\|x'-y'\|+1. $

This latter equation reminds me of the one that we must prove. But i can't proceed with those observations. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $M$. This means, that for $\epsilon = 1$, there exists $\delta$ such that $|x - y| < \delta \implies |f(x) -  f(y)| < 1$ for all $x,y \in M$.

Fix $x,y \in M$ and define $z_k = x + k\frac {\delta}{2} \frac{y-x}{||y-x||}$ for $k = 0,1,2,...,N$ where $N = \left\lfloor\frac{2||y-x||}{\delta}\right\rfloor$.

From the convexity of $M$, each $z_k \in M$. Also, $z_0 = x$, $||z_k  - z_{k-1}|| = \frac \delta 2$ and $||y-z_N|| < \frac \delta 2$, which I leave you to see yourself.

Therefore, $$
||f(y) - f(x)|| \leq \sum_{k=1}^N ||f(z_k) - f(z_{k-1})|| + ||f(y) - f(z_N)|| < (N + 1) \leq \frac{2||y-x||}{\delta} + 1
$$

Now, pick $a = \frac 2 \delta$ to conclude the argument. Since $x,y$ were arbitrary, this is true for all $x,y \in M$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Let me see if I really understood the argument: proving that $||z_k  - z_{k-1}|| = \frac \delta 2$ and $||y-z_N|| < \frac \delta 2$ is a necessary condition to use the fact that for those points $\|f(x)-f(y)\|<1.$ Also, the sum $ \sum_{k=1}^N ||f(z_k) - f(z_{k-1})||$ telescopes, leaving only $f(z_N)-f(z_0)=f(z_N) - f(x)$, which is consistent with the left side of the inequality. Since its is true $\|f(x)-f(y)\|<1$ for those points, we have proven that $\|f(y)-f(x)\| < N+1$, which by definition of $N$ gives us the required result.

Comment: Yes, you have got the gist of the argument.